# sorting of email-ID's using angular Filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular Filters.

If i want to sort the email Id's which is in ng-repeat by applying a filter. How to do this?

For example :

> xyz3@gmail.com,  xyz1@gmail.com , xyz2@gmail.com and abc1@gmail.com  are my emails.

I want to get the output as

> abc1@gmail.com , xyz1@gmail.com,  xyz2@gmail.com , xyz3@gmail.com

Its like sorting alphabetically and also in ascending order Both in a filter.

I would really appreciate if working code is provided for this.

Thanks in advance.  What I should write in OrderBy: "???????"

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 " ng-repeat="e in allEmails | orderBy:'??????'"> 
    //Display the emails here in sorted alphabetically ascending order.
</div>
```

Comment: orderBy:'toString()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  $scope.emails =  ['xyz3@gmail.com', 'xyz1@gmail.com', 'xyz2@gmail.com', 'abc1@gmail.com']
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="email in emails |orderBy:'toString()'">
        {{email}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

Comment: I have a strange problem here. I am exporting the emails from excel file. For some wered reason it is not sorting all the emails.  Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: For example if emails are like this xyz1@gmail.com , xyz10@gmail.com, xyz100@gmail.com, xyz11@gmail.com, xyz12@gmail.com,  xyz13@gmail.com . The output i am getting is  xyz100@gmail.com , xyz10@gmail.com, xyz1@gmail.com, xyz11@gmail.com .  xyz12@gmail.com, xyz13@gmail.com

Comment: Try this filter , 
http://blog.overzealous.com/post/55829457993/natural-sorting-within-angularjs

Comment: Hi Rejs. So do we need to write like this orderBy:natural('????')... What should I place in ?????..  can you please help me with working example. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: That is because '@' comes first than any number. You should make a filter to order the string that comes before the '@'

Answer (score 1):

Here is another response creating [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) `mySortFilter`:

```js
angular
  .module('myapp', [])
  .filter('mySortFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input.sort();
    }
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.emails =  ['xyz3@gmail.com', 'xyz1@gmail.com', 'xyz2@gmail.com', 'abc1@gmail.com'] 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="email in emails | mySortFilter">
        {{email}}
     </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`orderBy: email`
You just have to order by the name of the variable. Ascending is default. 
If your variable were `$scope.email.addresses = [];`
then you would have to filter like this:

`orderBy: email.addresses`

Comment: As I answered: email